# What is the relationship between maximum entropy sampling and bayesian d-optimal design?

Tags: regression, experiment-design, maximum-entropy, active-learning

In regards to optimal design, specifically sequential design or active learning for parameter inference (e.g. linear regression). As I understand it, Bayesian D-optimal design maximises the expected information gain (the mutual information), within a Bayesian framework - that is we are including the prior, and likelihood function. How is this any different from maximum entropy sampling - are we only neglecting the Bayesian framework? That is, for maximum entropy design are we only maximising the determinant of the Fisher information matrix, whereas in D-optimal design we are maximising the prior precondition Fisher information matrix?